# How do you use environment variables in a ReasonReact app?

Tags: reason, reason-react

I tried adding a `.env` file to the root of my directory and I tried accessing the contents with

`[@bs.val] external graphqlUrl : string = "process.env.GRAPHQL_URL";`

but it when I `Js.log(graphqlUrl);` it's `undefined`!

`.env` file:

```
GRAPHQL_URL=https://api.example.com
```

How do I access it?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using webpack? If you are, this can be configured using a plugin. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack

Comment: Noted sir. I'll try that out. Thanks! I'll inform you what happens afterwards.

Comment: That worked sir [@RemLampa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6625014/rem-lampa)! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed sir [Rem Lampa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6625014/rem-lampa)'s suggestion and installed [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) on my project. Then I followed the instructions on the `dotenv-webpack` docs.

The `webpack.config.js` file now looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const outputDir = path.join(__dirname, "build/");

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/Index.bs.js',
  mode: isProd ? 'production' : 'development',
  output: {
    path: outputDir,
    publicPath: outputDir,
    filename: 'Index.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv()
  ]
};
```

Comment: https://reasonml.chat/t/reading-env-variables-with-reason-and-or-reason-scripts/485